# test floats next to navigation bar instead of above

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

I was trying to create a "hamburger menu" but every time I would input the picture, it would go next to the navigation instead of above the div. So I tested it out with text and it is still floating next to navigation. I researched this and couldn't find an answer. I am trying make it float up instead of next to navigation bar. Html will be posted here and rest will be in codepen.

Demo:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWjaYV

html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"> 

             <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="magicstyle.css">

        </head>     
        <body>
            <!-- Section for Jobs Popup -->
                 <div id="job-popup">
            <div class="x-div1"><img class="x-icon1" id="fadeX1" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png" alt="Text alternative when image is not available"></div>
            <div id="job-content">

                <h1 id="jobWords"></h1>

                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- Section for Contact Popup -->
            <div id="contact-popup">
            <div class="x-div2"><img class="x-icon2" id="fadeX2" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
            <div id="contact-content">

                <h1 id="contactWords"></h1>

                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Section for Press Popu -->
             <div id="press-popup">
            <div class="x-div3"><img class="x-icon3" id="fadeX3" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
            <div id="press-content">

                <h1 id="pressWords"></h1>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="legal-popup">
            <div class="x-div4"><img class="x-icon4" id="fadeX4" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
            <div id="legal-content">

                <h1 id="legalWords"></h1>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="support-popup">
            <div class="x-div5"><img class="x-icon5" id="fadeX5" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
            <div id="support-content">

                <h1 id="supportWords"></h1>

                </div>

            </div>



                <div id="top-bar">

                        <a class="burger-nav"></a>
                    <p id="testText">dkdd</p>
                    <div id="nav-menu">
                    <span id="job">Jobs</span>
                    <span id="contact">Contact</span>
                    <span id="press">Press</span>
                    <span id="legal">Legal</span>
                    <span id="support">Support</span>

                    </div>


                </div>
            <div id="container">


                <div id="name-div">
                <h1 id="name">Open Touch</h1>
                </div>
                <ul class="bubbles">

            <li id="firstCircle"></li>
            <li id="secondCircle"></li>
            <li id="thirdCircle"></li>
            <li id="fourthCircle"></li>
            <li id="fifthCircle"></li>
            <li id="sixthCircle"></li>



            </ul>



            </div>



        </body>





</html>
```

Any type of help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I added to `<div id="name-div" style="position: relative; top: 21px;">`. The problem is that I do not have a clear Idea of what you want to achieve

This is my screenshot. If I bring this text more up (with `top:` you can go negative) there will be some overflow problem. I don't know if we should fix it. So let me know

Thanks
[image]

Comment: @thatoneguy90 but the best way to solve it could be using flexbox, this is more of a simple solution. Depends what you want to achieve

Comment: I am trying to get my text back in its original spot. Because in the html, the text is suppose to be above the navigation bar but now its right next to it.

Comment: @thatoneguy90 attach a screenshot of what you want to accomplish. you set your div below the navigation bar. i can not understand what you want to accomplish

Answer (score -1):

Well I solved it by applying the "min-height:0" to the "top-bar" which seem to fix it. Now when I add more text, the div adjust to the text instead of letting it overflow in it.